# How to get href attribute in puppeteer Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

I want to extract the information from a table using `puppeteer` and NodeJS. But I need help getting the link from a table cell. The table has no class names or IDs.
This is the closest I've gotten:

`url: e.getElementsByTagName("td")[3].innerHTML`

This gives me the following:

```
{
    cellText: 'AFC',
    url: '<a href="/wiki/Asian_Football_Confederation" title="Asian Football Confederation">AFC</a>'
  },
  { cellText: '', url: '' }
```

Do you know how I can get this below?:

```
{
    cellText: 'AFC',
    url: "/wiki/Asian_Football_Confederation"
  },
```

This is the code with a random website:

```
const pupperteer = require("puppeteer");

async function run() {
    const browser = await pupperteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto("https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/2022_FIFA_World_Cup_Group_A")

    const myArray = await page.$$eval("table[class*='sortable'", (elements) =>
        elements.map((e) => ({
            cellText: e.getElementsByTagName("td")[3].innerText,
            url: e.getElementsByTagName("td")[3].innerHTML
        }))
    );

    console.log(myArray);

    await browser.close();
}

run();
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you shared details of the HTML markup you are working with and trying to extract information from. Look into `.querySelector()` to select your link elements and `.getAttribute()` to retrieve the `href` attribute values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to select a single element, I'd avoid `getElementsByTagName` here in favor of the one-shot `table[class*="sortable"] td:nth-child(4)`. This selects the table you're targeting, then grabs the fourth `td` from the first row of data cells.

To get the href, add a second query based on the nodes inside the above-selected cell element: `element.querySelector("a")`.

Putting it together:

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer"); // ^19.0.0

let browser;
(async () => {
  browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const [page] = await browser.pages();
  const url = "https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/2022_FIFA_World_Cup_Group_A";
  await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: "domcontentloaded"});
  const sel = 'table[class*="sortable"] td:nth-child(4)';
  const result = await page.$eval(sel, e => ({
    cellText: e.textContent,
    url: e.querySelector("a").href
  }));
  console.log(result);
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close());
```

Considering the text content and link are one and the same in this case, you can simplify this further to a single selector for only the anchor tag within the target `<td>`:

```js
// ...
const sel = 'table[class*="sortable"] td:nth-child(4) a';
const result = await page.$eval(sel, e => ({
  cellText: e.textContent,
  url: e.href
}));
// ...
```

Since the data is statically present in the HTML, you don't need Puppeteer for this. It's probably better to use a lightweight HTTP request and a HTML parser like Cheerio. For example:

```js
const cheerio = require("cheerio"); // 1.0.0-rc.12

const url = "https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/2022_FIFA_World_Cup_Group_A";

fetch(url)
  .then(res => res.text())
  .then(html => {
    const $ = cheerio.load(html);
    const sel = 'table[class*="sortable"] td:nth-child(4)';
    const result = {
      cellText: $(sel).first().text(),
      url: $(sel).find("a").attr("href")
    };
    console.log(result);
  });
```